# What leads to Mathlink connection lost when running

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, licensing

My C program called Mathematica several times during the execution. However, after 4 or 5 times Mathematica stopped and then I got this message.

> /home/sec/.Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass:3:  The Mathematica
>   license you are using has expired.    Please contact Wolfram Research or
>   an authorized     Mathematica distributor to extend your license and
>     obtain a new password. Error detected by MathLink: MathLink
>   connection was lost..

Is this the licence problem or technical problem? I am using Mathematica 9 Student right now.

Thanks,

Comment: You create a new kernel every time without shutting down the previous one? maybe you have reached the maximum number of parallel kernel executions. When this message appears, check how many kernel instances you have.

Comment: @Jepessen thank you, I just figured out that I didn't close the channel after opening it.

Comment: @Jepessen please consider posting the answer :)

Comment: Ok, I've done it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a new kernel every time without shutting down the previous one? maybe you have reached the maximum number of parallel kernel executions. When this message appears, check how many kernel instances you have.